Afterlife movie about three people found themselves in a house that they could not leave after death
Some years ago, I saw a movie that centered around three people who had been in life-threatening accidents. They found themselves in a house that they could not leave. An angel of sorts (kind of like Mr. Jordan in Heaven Can Wait) keeps popping in and out, letting them know how things are progressing since they are in a waiting area of sorts. There is a young business man (late 30s to early 40s), a middle-aged middle-management-type woman, and a woman with blonde hair who is in her late 20s or early 30s. I think the blonde woman has a guitar. Near the end, they are informed that they must decide who will return to their life.

First of all, welcome to Movies & TV! Second, thanks for being so detailed in the plot description. But is there any chance you have any non-plot-related details that you could share to help us identify the movie more easily? e.g. Any idea when the movie came out (even a ballpark estimate)? Or where the movie was from/what language it was in? Thanks!

The movie I was looking for was made in 1991 and was called 'In Between'.

Three strangers - two women and one man - find themselves trapped
  inside an unfamiliar house with no recollection of how they got there.
  They soon discover that the house has been borrowed to serve as a
  temporary way station between life and death.



I think it's Enter nowhere: 

Three strangers arrive one by one at a mysterious cabin in the middle of nowhere only to learn they've been brought together for a reason.

It was great movie

You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

The Blonde woman had long blonde hair it was english and may have been made in the 90's also the house they were in seemed to be by the beach. The owner was on vacation at one point it seemed he came back but turned around and left before coming in

The movie Enter Nowhere was not the movie I,m trying to find all the actors were americans. Still hoping someone knows the name of it.

I do remember the man had been in a car accident. The middle aged woman had been out drinking with co workers and was attacked when she left the bar she was raped and beaten and her body thrown in a dumpster. The young woman had been murdered by a friend.
